# form isset doesn't work with jquery

Tags: sql, forms, submit, isset

Hello I'm working on a image browser where I've a submit button to add a new row to the database. Unfortunately the isset function isn't working. When I remove this if statement it works fine, but when  use if(isset($_POST['addImg'])) nothing happens.

image browser has the form:

```
<div id="galleryAdd">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >     
        <!-- een hidden id meegeven voor de plaatsing -->
        <input type="hidden" name="parentID" value="<? //$_GET['b']?>40">
        <input type="submit" name="addImg" value="Toevoegen" />
    </form> 
</div>
<div id="addExisting"></div>
```

javascript is calling page load when clicking on an image item:

```
$('.imgItem').click(function() {
        $('.imgItem').removeClass("image_select");
        $(this).addClass("image_select");   
        var imgsource = $(this).find('img').attr('src'),
            folderID = $(this).find('img').attr('rel');
        $("#addExisting").load("ajax.addExisting.php", {parentID:folderID, imgsource:imgsource});
        return false;   
    });
```

ajax.existing.php : page that is loaded when clicking an image

```
/* Algemene Gegevens bestand */
$bestand = $_POST['imgsource'];

/* Meta Gegevens bestand */
$file = substr($bestand, 0,strrpos($bestand,'.'));
$ext = substr(strrchr($bestand,'.'),1);
$base = basename($file);


if(isset($_POST['addImg'])){
/* Parent */
$queryParent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `image_folders` WHERE id = ".$_POST['parentID'].""); 
$parent = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryParent);
$bestand_folder = "../../images/".$parent['dirname']."/";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (positie, parent, parentID, naam, alt, titel, extensie) VALUES ('99', '".$parent['name']."', '".$parent['id']."', '".$base."', '".$base."',     '".$base."','".$ext."')")or die('kan niet uploaden'.mysql_error());

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you are not posting the `addImg`.

You only sent to the ajax page the `{parentID:folderID, imgsource:imgsource}`

change

```
$("#addExisting").load("ajax.addExisting.php", {
                              parentID:folderID, 
                              imgsource:imgsource});
```

to

```
$("#addExisting").load("ajax.addExisting.php", {
                              parentID:folderID, 
                              imgsource:imgsource,  
                              addImg:'Toevoegen'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the `addImg` field in your `.load()` call. The only fields you're sending are `parentID` and `imgsource`. If you want `addImg`, add it to the arguments of `.load()`.